# Search string in a directory

Tags: windows, vbscript, hta

I am  trying to create a VBScript code that can take user input (string, directory) and search the directory for the string.

My .vbs file is here:

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dirname = InputBox("Enter Dir name")
Searchterm = Inputbox("Enter search term")

ProcessFolder DirName

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    Set Fls = fldr.Files
    For Each thing In Fls
        Set contents = thing.OpenAsTextStream 
        If Instr(contents.readall, searchterm) Then WScript.Echo thing.Path
    Next

    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
    For Each thing In fldrs
'        WScript.Echo thing.name
        ProcessFolder thing.path
    Next
End Sub
```

This works reasonable. However, when I try to wrap it in an HTA file I am not able to figure out how to pass form values and then show result on the HTML page.

Here is how I tried to create the .hta file:

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Simple Validation</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript"> 
Sub Submit_OnClick
    Dim TheForm
    Set TheForm = Document.ValidForm
    Dim FileName  

    On Error Resume Next
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strTemp = "result.txt"
    Dirname = TheForm.Text1.Value
    Searchterm = TheForm.Text2.Value
    Set objOutFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(strTemp,True)

    ProcessFolder DirName

    ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    Set Fls = fldr.files
    For Each thing In Fls
        Set contents = thing.OpenAsTextStream 
        If InStr(contents.ReadAll, searchterm) Then Set FileName = thing.Path"
    Next

    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
    For Each thing In fldrs
'        WScript.Echo thing.Name
        ProcessFolder thing.Path
    Next
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H3>Simple Validation</H3><HR>
<FORM NAME="ValidForm" align = "center">
Enter String to Serach: 
<INPUT NAME="Text1" TYPE="TEXT">
</br>
</br>
Enter Directory:
<INPUT NAME="Text2" TYPE="TEXT">
</br>
</br>
<INPUT NAME="Submit" TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Submit">
</FORM>

<p id = "demo"></p>

</BODY>
<script LANGUAGE = "javascript">
//document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = FileName;
</script>
</HTML>
```

Maybe I could show the result in a list or store it in a text file and access it to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTA is fundamentally broken.

1. If you're writing an [HTA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should include the actual [HTA tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

   ```
   <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA" APPLICATIONNAME="Test" ...>
   ```
2. The VBScript code block contains just one procedure definiton (`Sub Submit_OnClick`). In it you call the procedure `ProcessFolder` (twice), but you never actually define it anywhere. You need to put that procedure definition before or after the definition of `Submit_OnClick` or you won't be able to call it:

   ```
   Sub Submit_OnClick
     ...
   End Sub

   Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
     ...
   End Sub
   ```
3. The following line has a spurious trailing double quote:

   ```
   If InStr(contents.ReadAll, searchterm) Then Set FileName = thing.Path"
   ```
4. In the same line, you cannot use a [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) statement for assigning a string (the path) to a variable. That keyword is reserved for assigning *objects* to variables and must be omitted when assinging primitive data types.
5. `WScript.Echo` doesn't work in HTAs, because the HTA script host doesn't provide a `WScript` object. Use the [`MsgBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function instead if you need to display messages.
6. When opening `objOutFile` you use `objFS`, but your actual `FileSystemObject` instance variable is `fso`.
7. For displaying search results in the HTML you need to modify the value of an HTML element, e.g.:

   ```
   demo.innerHtml = demo.innerHtml & thing.Path & "<br>"
   ```

Comment: Thanks.... I started with vb-script just today.. :-) changing my hta file as per your suggestions...